# How to avoid exposing secret informations in vimrc when pushing it to Github

Tags: security, git, vim

I created  a new repository in Github to share my vimfiles.

But there's some problems.
In the vimrc file, I put some secret informations there to use some plugins.

For example, to use TwitVim( a Twitter client for Vim ), I should add the following codes.

```
let twitvim_login = "user:pass"
```

So every time I want to push my vimrc to Github, I have to delete them, and then add them again.

How could I avoid this. Is there any good solution to make this easier?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a file called `.secretpass` and add

> let twitvim_login = "user:pass"

in that file, in your `.vimrc` do;

```
source .secretpass
```

Comment: and don't forget to add .secretpass to your .gitignore

Comment: and if you've held vimrc under version control for a while, be wary about pushing it to github as the history will include versions prior to the password being removed (although you could always change your password).